# Environment variable expansion in gmake

Tags: gnu-make

I am facing the problem with the below code in gmake, where as it works ok with clearmake.

```
TEST_ENV :=
TEST_ENV +=
ifdef TEST_ENV
     TEST_ENV += Hello
endif
all:
        echo TEST_ENV=${TEST_ENV}
```

When we run this makefile in clearmake, TEST_ENV is not defined and it is not entered into ifdef block, where as in gmake, TEST_ENV is getting defined and entering into ifdef block.

Output:

In clearmake  :  `TEST_ENV=`

In gmake    :    `TEST_ENV=Hello`

How to write conditional statement which is common to clearmake and gmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response's.

It is working with strip function.

`TEST_ENV :=`
`TEST_ENV +=`
`ifeq ($(strip $(TEST_ENV)),)`
`endif`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running clearmake in GNU make emulation mode, this is a bug in clearmake that should be reported.  Other than that, you didn't say which of the two behaviors you preferred so we can't really help you.

Whenever you append a value to a variable, a space is always added between the old value and the new value.  Even if one or both of the values is an empty string, the space is still added.  So your example:

```
TEST_ENV :=
TEST_ENV +=
```

actually leaves `TEST_ENV` as containing a space, and that is not empty according to make (to make, empty means a zero-length string).

If you want to treat a string containing only whitespace as empty, you can use this:

```
ifeq($(strip $(TEST_ENV)),)
    TEST_ENV += Hello
endif
```

Or alternatively you can use:

```
TEST_ENV :=
TEST_ENV +=

TEST_ENV := $(strip $(TEST_ENV))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

But what I want is, in gmake I want how to differentiate the below two cases:

`TEST_ENV +=`
`TEST_ENV += Hello` 

If my TEST_ENV contains Hello (Some string), I want

Comment: In gmake, if my variable is set to empty, I dont want to enter into if block and variable is set to non empty I want to enter into if block. Please help me in this.

Comment: Before the `ifdef`, `TEST_ENV` contains a single space (in _gmake_ at least). Do you consider this to be empty, or non-empty?

Comment: If you want to count a variable containing only spaces as empty, then you should use `$(strip $(TEST_ENV))` to get rid of them.

Comment: @ bobogo, I consider that as empty string. TO be more specific, I want to differentiate a ENV variable contatining a single space and containing some string.

Comment: `TEST_ENV :=`
`TEST_ENV +=` 

`TEST_ENV1 += $(strip $(TEST_ENV))` 


`ifdef TEST_ENV1`

`endif`

Comment: No, that won't work.  It will work if you use `TEST_ENV1 := $(strip $(TEST_ENV))`.  The manual says:  _[ifdef] does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty._  If you use recursive variables then the value is `$(strip $(TEST_ENV))` which is not empty.  But that's not what I meant when I suggested `strip`.